# Android BUILD FAILED while release apk

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

The following warning causes building the apk to fail.

> ```
> Warning:jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer: can't find referenced method 'java.util.Enumeration getInitParameterNames()' in program class jcifs.http.NetworkExplorer.
> ```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you like to include some related code or a question to that warning?

Comment: Post more information on the error and if possible some code would be good.

Comment: Mention -dontwarn jcifs.http.** in proguard file & then build.

Comment: looks like either AS exception or some dependency you are are using needs to be ecluded from proguard

Comment: @VVB it working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your progaurd file

```
-keep class jcifs.** { *; }
 -dontwarn jcifs.http.**
```